# ubuntu recognizes my partition as free space whereas it contains data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, lvm

I have an internal HDD which I use it on another computer where it contains two operating systems (Windows and Linux). I connect it to my laptop via cable and mistakenly deleted the first partition of it. now it recognizes my other partitions as free space whereas it contains data.
here is the output  of `gpart /dev/sdb`:

```
Begin scan...
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(500mb), offset(1mb)
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(199500mb), offset(501mb)
Possible partition(Linux swap), size(5721mb), offset(200002mb)
Possible partition(Linux ext2), size(47676mb), offset(205724mb)
Possible extended partition at offset(253400mb)
   Possible partition(Linux ext2), size(700468mb), offset(253401mb)
End scan.

Checking partitions...

* Warning: more than 3 primary partitions: 4.
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): primary 
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): primary 
Partition(Linux swap or Solaris/x86): primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): primary 
   Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): logical 
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 007(0x07)(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX)
   size: 500mb #s(1024000) s(2048-1026047)
   chs:  (0/32/33)-(63/221/30)d (0/32/33)-(63/221/30)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 007(0x07)(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX)
   size: 199500mb #s(408576000) s(1026048-409602047)
   chs:  (63/221/31)-(1023/254/63)d (63/221/31)-(25496/139/51)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 130(0x82)(Linux swap or Solaris/x86)
   size: 5721mb #s(11716792) s(409604096-421320887)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (25496/172/21)-(26226/3/9)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 131(0x83)(Linux ext2 filesystem)
   size: 47676mb #s(97640448) s(421322752-518963199)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (26226/32/47)-(32303/246/7)r
```

here is the output of `disks`:

[image]

the 525 MB partition as the partition which I delete mistakenly, and 790 GB free space contains two ext4 partitions

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: `gpart` looks like it thinks this was an MBR partition table.  are you certain the original was MBR and not GPT?  you might consult TestDisk or another tool; i see nothing in `gpart` documentation that indicates it handles GPT.

Comment: are you using a GPT disk? how are you checking the drives; a LiveCD?

Comment: @quixotic it is an MBR partition table

Comment: @ravery my main SSD which I'm using now (sda) is GPT but this hard disk (sdb) is MBR

Comment: then partition 3 is an Extended partition. with 2 logical drives in it?

Comment: @ravery yes it is

Comment: the logical partitions aren't showing because, gpart isn't recognizing the extended partition (it is marked unknown). Have you tried booting from a LiveCD and using gparted?

Comment: `testdisk`, as already stated, is a very good tool especially when you deleted partitions or repartitioned a disk.